# Understanding the difference between text files and binary files

Tags: file, text, binary

I just want to make sure I understand something.

If my understanding is correct, everything on the computer is saved in binary form, which means it's all saved as a series of bits which are ones and zeroes. 'Binary files' are saved this way, and so are text files.

Technically, binary files and text files are the same: they're both a series of bits. The only difference is that a text file is supposed to be parsed and translated to a series of characters by a program that knows how to do this, according to some encoding. So for example a `.txt` file is just a binary file - a series of bits - but a word processor such as Notepad knows how to translate each byte to a character you see on the screen.

That's all the difference. Am I correct?

Also, the reason why it's more efficient to work with 'binary form' than with 'textual form' is because in text, each character is encoded as a byte, i.e. 8 bits, while in 'binary form' each byte can have a full meaning and you don't need to waste a number of bytes just to say the simplest thing. Is this correct?

Answer (score -2):

**NOTE:** Let us keep multi-byte charsets aside for easy understanding.

**NOTE:** Considering Unix which uses ASCII for text files (other encodings are not considered for simplicity)

---

Let us understand the difference between string and array of characters

In a byte of `8 bits`, we can store `0 to 255` if *unsigned*, `-128 to +127` if *signed*

As a whole, if we see a byte (`8 bits`) the value that can be fit into it is `-128 to 255` (range). The range of ASCII characters (`0 to 127`).

Given character array `a[10]` if any of the bytes `a[0] to a[9]` has value out of the range of ASCII character range then it is not a **string**, its just array of characters. If all of the bytes fall within the ASCII range (`0 to 127`) then it is **string**.

In summary for the array of characters, the range can be any of (`-128 to 255`).

Important conclusion here is since ASCII range (`0 to 127`) is a proper subset of `-128 to 255` All **strings** can be called the array of characters.

Now let us apply the above definition to ***binary*** file vs **text** file.

If in a file all bytes are in the range of ASCII (`0 to 127`) it should be called a **text** file.

If any of them falls out of this range i.e any of `(-128 to -1`) or (`128 to 255`) then it is a **binary** file.

In summary, since ASCII range `0 to 127` is a proper subset of (`-128 to 255`) **all text files are binary files**.

If a file has atleast one byte from (`-128 to -1`) or (`128 to 255`) **it cannot be text file only binary file**.

I have not verified standards if any of ASCII range character(s) has special treatment. But in summary I think I made the distinction behind **text file** vs **binary file** clear.

Hope this helps

Comment: *"If in a file all bytes are in range of (32 to 96) it should be called TEXT file."* - Definitely not. Imagine your compiler producing an executable file that just happens to fulfill that all bytes lies in this range. Would you consider it a text file?

Comment: Files are not distinguished based on whether they can be executed or not. Thats what i clarified on the top. E.g: Though shell script is executable it is still text file. Files are classified based on what each byte contain. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: What you are saying is that some files containing pure machine code is text files.

Comment: Btw, I could use the same argument for jpg image files or something else.

Comment: It doesnt matter whether it is machine core or something else what i say is if every byte in a file is in range (32 to 96) it is strictly TEXT file. However understand that "All text files are binary files"

Comment: Which is wrong. Files containing bytes outside a certain range is non-text files. That much is true, but there are also non-text files that only contain bytes within that range.

Comment: The above definition is accurate. All files are binary. (not sure what you mean by non-text). Range (-127 to 255). Some files are TEXT files (32 to 96). This is what i have explained in detail

Comment: (32 to 96) is typo it is (32 to 126).

Comment: Still, this post is very wrong. If a file is a text file or not depends on what the bytes represent rather than their actual values.

Answer (score -3):

Binary stores 0-255 in a single byte (8 bits)
Text mode will store 105 as a set of 3 characters (with is one byte each, in ASCII) '1', '0', '5'.

You can open the text file and see '105', but the binary for 105 is not human recognizable, and is much more efficient and easier for the machine to read.

There are other differences as well, but that is the main point.

Comment: It's unlikely that the character set and encoding are ASCII. For decades on many systems it's been Unicode/UTF-8 or Windows-1252 (or similar). UTF-8 does not always use one byte per character.

Comment: For clarity I chose to focus on principle alone.  And I did specify it was ASCII, he'll encounter UTF-8 when he's ready.

Comment: I agree that learning is iterative but I see ASCII not as a stepping stone but a misdirection.